# Parse won't compile

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

So I'm just trying to set up my new app with parse. I've downloaded their SDK and I've pasted my applicationID. The problem is in push notifications (which I didn't even touch). Can someone please help me?
Thanks

ERROR CODE:

```
   PFPush.subscribeToChannelInBackground("") { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) in
        if succeeded {
            print("ParseStarterProject successfully subscribed to push notifications on the broadcast channel.\n");
        } else {
            print("ParseStarterProject failed to subscribe to push notifications on the broadcast channel with error = %@.\n", error)
        }
    }
}
```

It says:

> Cannot invoke 'subscribeToChannelInBackground' with an argument list
>   of type '(String, (Bool, NSError?) -> ())'

Comment: You did not write that code? But it was already there? Are you using the correct framework version matching your swift version?

Comment: Yes, that was already there. How do I check wheter my version is correct or not? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are showing is to subscribe to notification channel...and it is complaining that it doesn't expect these arguments type.

To set up Parse SDK follow this: https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/swift/existing

from the parse getting started guide, this is how they tested the installation was good to go (swift)

```
let testObject = PFObject(className: "TestObject")
testObject["foo"] = "bar"
testObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  print("Object has been saved.")
}
```

Comment: Sorry. Since I'm starting developer, can you tell me more precisely where should I implement the code you just gave me? Thanks

Comment: in the viewDidLoad method of your view controller. Upon executing the code, you will see that your Parse table will have a new class and row in it.

Comment: @AntonN check the link I shared...it has step by step of how to install it and what also you need to add in terms of libraries to support Parse

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the syntax of the function call is wrong. Follow the function (right click on the function in Xcode and "Jump to definition") to find out which arguments exactly the function expects. I don't know the SDK, but I guess the function takes two arguments - a string and a closure (block). Then you need to use that in your call instead of whatever you are using now.